# Tables and Images in LaTeX

Tags: tables, graphics, columns

I am trying to add multiple rows of text in front of an image in tables in `LaTeX`. It basically consists of four columns, I am using `table` and `tabular*` ....

[image]

this is the code I am using

```
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{ }

  \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}
{p{0.2\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}>%{\centering}p{0.1\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}>
{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.2\textwidth}}
 \hline
   \centering  C1 & \centering \centering C2 & \centering C3 &  C4 \\
    \hline\\
  \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{figs/M1.PNG}}
&  R1 {1}     &        R1{2}   &  R1{3} & R1{4} \\
&  R2 {1}     &        R2{2}   &  R2{3} & R2{4} \\
  \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1]{figs/M2.PNG}}
&  R3 {1}     &        R3{2}   &  R3{3} & R3{4} \\
&  R4 {1}     &        R4{2}   &  R4{3} & R4{4} \\

  \end{tabular*}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? In lack of information what is your problem I guess that this can serve as starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} *{2}{X[c,m]X[l,m]}},
               rowsep  = 1pt }
    \SetCell[r=4]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-duck}
        &   first row   
            &   \SetCell[r=4]{c}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-duck}
                &   first row   \\
        & second row
            &   &   second row  \\
        & third row
            &   &   third row  \\
        & fourth row
            &   &   fourth row  \\
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{???}\label{fig:??}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Why you not immediately show us what you try so far? Anyway, above example is good enough starting point that you should be able to insert your real table content (BTW, it is not entirely clear, what your table should show).

More  important is, do you like to have both images and tables in one line or in the two, as can be concluded from your code fragment.

All what you need to do, is define more columns for your tables contents.

- The first example: both images and tables are in one line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % <--- added
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}% <--- added
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \small % <--- added
  \begin{tblr}{colsep=3pt,
               colspec = {@{} *{2}{X[c] *{4}{Q[c,m]}}  @{}}, % <--- changed
               vspan=even} % <--- added
    \SetCell[r=2]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-duck}
        & R1 \{1\} & R1 \{2\} & R1 \{3\} & R1 \{4\}
            &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}
                \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-duck}
                & R3 \{1\} & R3 \{2\} & R3 \{3\} & R3 \{4\}   \\
        & R2 \{1\} & R2 \{2\} & R2 \{3\} & R2 \{4\}
            &   & R4 \{1\} & R4 \{2\} & R4 \{3\} & R4 \{4\}   \\
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{???}\label{fig:??}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- The second example: images and tables are in two lines line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \small
  \begin{tblr}{width=0.9\linewidth,
               colspec = {@{} X[c] *{4}{Q[c,m]}   @{}},
               vspan=even}
    \SetCell[r=2]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-duck}
        & R1 \{1\} & R1 \{2\} & R1 \{3\} & R1 \{4\}     \\
        & R2 \{1\} & R2 \{2\} & R2 \{3\} & R2 \{4\}     \\
    \SetCell[r=2]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-duck}
        & R3 \{1\} & R3 \{2\} & R3 \{3\} & R3 \{4\}   \\
        & R4 \{1\} & R4 \{2\} & R4 \{3\} & R4 \{4\}   \\
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{???}\label{fig:??}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thnks for your answer .....I basically needs a wide table with the following content....
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{ }

  \begin{tabular*}{ccccc}
   \centering  C1 & \centering \centering C2 & \centering C3 &  C4 \\
    \hline\\
\includegraphics[scale=1]{figs/M1.PNG}
&  R1 {1}     &        R1{2}   &  R1{3} & R1{4} \\
&  R2 {1}     &        R2{2}   &  R2{3} & R2{4} \\
{\includegraphics[scale=1]{figs/M2.PNG}}
&  R3 {1}     &        R3{2}   &  R3{3} & R3{4} \\
&  R4 {1}     &        R4{2}   &  R4{3} & R4{4} \\

  \end{tabular*}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table*}

Comment: @Geetanjlisharma,why you not add this code at the first place? Do you try to insert it in my MWE? BTW, now your question is less clear what is your problem.